# Jobs not connecting to MySQL service for self hosted GitHub Actions on ECS

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ecs, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have a self hosted GitHub Actions running in ECS and it has been working wonders, until I have to deal with service discovery.

The below is the workflow file

```
name: Checks before merging for core-service server

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'tons/of/paths/**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, x64, nomad]

    #set a timeout just in case the tests hang
    timeout-minutes: 5

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test-db
          MYSQL_USER: user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        ports:
          - 3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js 14.16
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: 14.16
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
      working-directory: some-dependency/location
    - name: Check if build is passing
      run: npm run build
      working-directory: more-dependency/more-places
    - name: Run tests
      run: npm run test
      env:
        DATABASE_URL: mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:${{ job.services.mysql.ports[3306] }}/test-db
      working-directory: core-service/server
```

The below is the error I'm getting

```
Using existing mysql database from: DATABASE_URL
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32777
```

Any comments will be appreciated.
Have a nice day~

Comment: Where is the DB relative to other assets in the stack (is it running in `RDS`)? If so, have the security groups been properly configured to allow traffic from all external components in the stack? Another thought: your config file shows all ports indicated as `3306` but your error is on port `32777`. Can you provide more details on that? `ECONNREFUSED` is often the result of network access architecture, or DB user and permission privileges missing or incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service discovery within GitHub seems to have implementation details that have not made it to self-hosted runners.

I found that self hosted jobs should access the MySQL service via `172.17.0.1` (the host address for default networking in Docker..?), and use service discovery to fetch the port.

More information regarding accessing the gateway host in ECS can be found here: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/165

```
name: Build

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: acme_test
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
        options: >-
          --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping"
          --health-interval=10s
          --health-timeout=5s
          --health-retries=3

    steps:       
      - name: Verify MySQL connection
        run: |
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt install -y mysql-client
          mysql --version
          mysql \
            --host 172.17.0.1 \
            --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} \
            -uroot
            -psecret -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
```